# Splitting char array

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I have a `char **names` array that basically stores names from a file.

This is my `.txt` file

```
Mike, Sam, Stuart
Andre, Williams, Phillips
Patels, Khan, Smith
```

Basically, I want to split and store the names before the `,` character.
For example, `Mike, Sam, Stuart` will become...

```
newName[0] = Mike
newName[1] = Sam
newName[2] = Stuart
```

I have something like this...

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
  for (int j=60, j>0; j--)
  {
     if(names[i][j] == ',')
     {
        cout << j << endl; //THIS PRINTS OUT THE POSITION. HOW CAN I STORE THE POSITION AND DO SOMETHING?
     }
  }
}
```

I would appreciate it if someone could help me with my code, it is in the right direction. I don't want to use any `vectors` classes

I have attempted to store marks of these students, however I want to add it to a `double *marks[2]` array.

This is my `.txt` file...

```
69.9, 56.5
29.8, 20.0
35.6, 45.0
```

This is my code...

```
char **values;
char * pch;
pch = strtok (values[i], " ,");
while (pch != NULL)
{
    sscanf(pch, "%f, %f", &marks[i][0], &marks[i][1]);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,");
}
```

I am getting random values such as `1.28277e-307` and `1.96471e+257`

Comment: Why not use std::string instead of character arrays?

Comment: `double *marks[2]` : pointer ??

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, yes I want to store the marks into the pointer array. I need some help

Comment: Why pointer? Why `2`?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY to store `2` marks per array. For example, `marks[0] = 69.9, 56.5` ; `marks[1] = 29.8, 20.0` and `marks[2] = 35.6, 45.0`

Comment: its not `double *marks[2]`.

Answer (score 3):

look up the strtok command it will be very helpful to you.

This code looks for hyphen characters and prints stuff... change it to commas

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   const char str[80] = "This is - www.tutorialspoint.com - website";
   const char s[2] = "-";

   char * newName[100]; /* at most 100 names */
   int iCurName = 0;


   char *token;

   /* get the first token */
   token = strtok(str, s);

   /* walk through other tokens */
   while( token != NULL ) 
   {
      printf( " %s\n", token );
      newName[iCurName] = malloc (char *) (strlen(token) + 1);
      strcpy(newName[iCurName],token);
      iCurrName ++;

      token = strtok(NULL, s);
   }

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, in my case how do I store the splitted characters into a new array. For example, `newName[0] = Mike`, `newName[1] = Sam`, `newName[2] = Stuart`

Comment: changing the answer to answer your question

Comment: something close to that.

Comment: @StuUser To populate your newName array with names, you can use `strcpy_s()` function
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
   char string[80];
   // using template versions of strcpy_s and strcat_s:
   strcpy_s( string, "Hello world from " );
   strcat_s( string, "strcpy_s " );
   strcat_s( string, "and " );
   // of course we can supply the size explicitly if we want to:
   strcat_s( string, _countof(string), "strcat_s!" );
   
   printf( "String = %s\n", string );
}

Answer (score 0):

Use function `strtok()` to split input line into tokens; use `strcpy_s()` to copy each token into name buffer.

**Note 1**: The `strtok()` function replaces each separator with `'\0'` character, so the `line` variable cannot be declared with `const`. If your input buffer must be constant, for example if you want to use the whole line for something else, make a copy of it before calling `strtok()` function.

**Note 2**: You might want to trim space in addition to splitting your input line.

```
#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 80
#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH 20
#define MAX_NAMES_PER_LINE 3

const char constInput = "Mike, Sam, Stewart";
char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
strcpy_s(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, constInput);

char *separator = ",";

char newName[MAX_NAMES_PER_LINE][MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
int i = 0;
char *token = strtok(line, separator);
while ((i < MAX_NAMES_PER_LINE) && ((token = strtok(NULL, separator)) != NULL))
{
    strcpy_s(newName[i++], MAX_NAME_LENGTH, token);
}
```

Comment: What about if I wanted to store decimals? For example, {(5.6, 9.0), (4.5, 9.0), (8.9, 2.0)}?

Comment: To convert strings to decimals, you can use different string conversion functions, for example, atof or sscanf.

Comment: Thanks for the `atof` function. Thanks for your response, I have attempted to store some numeric values (see edited post at the top) into a `double` array but I am having some difficulty. Basically, for every line I want to store both values into the same array, i.e. (`marks[0][0] = 56.9`, `marks[0][1] = 45.6`), (`marks[1][0] = 16.9`, `marks[1][1] = 15.6`)

Comment: @StuUser, you use strtok correctly in the last code section of the edited post, however the way you parse values into marks is not right. Try sscanf(values[i], "%f, %f", &marks[i][0], &marks[i][1]);   
where values[i] is a line of marks, like "5.6, 9.0"

Comment: thanks, but I am now getting random values such as `1.28277e-307` and `1.96471e+257`

Comment: @StuUser because you are trying to read two numbers from `pch`, which is one number token in your code. Try `float x = atof(pch);`

Answer (score 0):

```
char newName[3][60];

for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
    int r=0, c=0;
    for (int j=0; j<60; j++){
        if(names[i][j] == ',' || names[i][j] == '\0'){
            newName[r++][c] = '\0';
            c = 0;
            if(names[i][j] == '\0'){
                cout << newName[0] << '\n'
                     << newName[1] << '\n'
                     << newName[2] << '\n' << endl;
                break;
            }
            while(names[i][++j] == ' ')
                ;
            --j;
        } else {
            newName[r][c++] = names[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream inf("data.txt");
    double marks[2];
    char ch;

    while(inf.good()){
        inf >> marks[0] >> ch >> marks[1];
        cout << "mark1:"  << marks[0] << endl;
        cout << "mark2:"  << marks[1] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: What about if I wanted to store decimals? For example, `{(5.6, 9.0), (4.5, 9.0), (8.9, 2.0)}`?

Comment: @StuUser If even numbers than it is stored as a string the same. But it is seems easy to read from a file as a numeric value.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have attempted to store some numeric values (see edited post at the top) into a `double` array but I am having some difficulty. Basically, for every line I want to store both values into the same array, i.e. (`marks[0][0] = 56.9`, `marks[0][1] = 45.6`), (`marks[1][0] = 16.9`, `marks[1][1] = 15.6`)

Comment: Thanks, please help me with my edited code in my question. Basically, I want to add the values to the same `marks[i][0]` and `marks[i][1]` array, but there is something with my checks.

Comment: @StuUser It will be on your own. I already showed sufficient sample.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this function works fast enough, but here it is:

```
char** split_quotes(char *input, char separator = ' ', bool keep_quotes = false)
{
    if (&input && input)
    {
        size_t length = strlen(input);
        char **chunks = new char*[length];

        bool inQuotes = false;
        size_t count = 0, from = 0;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            if (input[i] == '"')
            {
                inQuotes = !inQuotes;
            }
            else if (input[i] == separator && !inQuotes)
            {
                size_t strlen = i - from;

                if (strlen > 0)
                {
                    if (!keep_quotes && input[from] == '"' && input[i - 1] == '"')
                    {
                        from++; strlen -= 2;
                    }

                    chunks[count] = new char[strlen + 1]();
                    strncpy(chunks[count], &input[from], strlen);
                    count++;
                }

                from = i + 1;
            }
        }

        if (from < length)
        {
            size_t strlen = length - from;

            if (!keep_quotes && input[from] == L'"' && input[length - 1] == L'"')
            {
                from++; strlen -= 2;
            }

            chunks[count] = new char[strlen + 1]();
            strncpy(chunks[count], &input[from], strlen);
            count++;
        }

        // Save chunks to result array //
        char **result = new char*[count + 1]();
        memcpy(result, chunks, sizeof(char*) * count);

        // free chunks //
        delete[] chunks;

        return result;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Usage:

```
wchar_t **name = split_quotes(L"Mike,Donald,\"My Angel\",Anna", L',');
if (name)
{
    while (*name++)
    { 
        std::wcout << "Person: " << *name << std::endl;
    }
}
```